# how to make linux cdrom mounting/unmounting show up in syslog

Tags: linux, mount, syslog

I'd like a record of every time the cdrom drive is mounted.  Ideally this would be in syslog. The system is CentOS 5.5 linux.

Answer (score 1):

While mounting a device, the mount command will issue an open system call. Thus, one approach is to use linux's audit subysystem to log reads on the cdrom device. First, you need to get it enabled.

```
yum install audit
chkconfig auditd on
service auditd start
auditctl -e 1
```

Now you need to figure out your cdrom device and add the rule to log reads.

```
readlink -f /dev/cdrom
auditctl -w /dev/sr0 -p r
```

Now if I have a shell with my working directory of /var/log and I run

```
mount /dev/sr0
```

Afterwards there will be three related lines in /var/log/audit/audit.log

> type=SYSCALL
>   msg=audit(1301280283.689:15549):
>   arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes
>   exit=3 a0=7f0d3af92820 a1=0 a2=0 a3=1
>   items=1 ppid=14660 pid=14661 auid=500
>   uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0
>   egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts4 ses=231
>   comm="mount" exe="/bin/mount"
>   key=(null)
>
> type=CWD
>   msg=audit(1301280283.689:15549): 
>   cwd="/var/log"
>
> type=PATH
>   msg=audit(1301280283.689:15549):
>   item=0 name="/dev/sr0" inode=5821
>   dev=00:05 mode=060660 ouid=0 ogid=11
>   rdev=0b:00

This approach isn't a good idea if there are other processes the regularly read the cdrom device. On a Fedora 14 system, the udisks-daemon seems to poll it every second. However, on a CentOS 5.5 system, there doesn't seem to be anything accessing it.

Comment: This works pretty well at getting the event logged to a file, but I was really hoping to be able to send it to syslog.